# The best way to write an FAQ page?

Tags: customization

I have a faq page that is likely to gross more than 50 questions and will need to be regularly modified and maintained.

I would like to write a title (possibly marked as header6, 5 or 4) and the answer below it. What i want is a way to generate links at the top of the page with the heading as the link text.

Whats the best/easiest way to do this? I was hoping maybe using MS word to generate the ToC for me and use it as an faq would work. Then I realized the ToC has no links. Maybe I can find something that generates html which I can copy/paste or something.

What is your suggestion for maintaining a large faq page?

Answer (score 2):

For one project, I created a Custom Post Type called FAQ. From there I just used a page-template to display all FAQ titles with the snippet and a "..Continue Reading" link . This way, if a particular FAQ answer was really long the user could just click to read more.
You could also design the page to not show the snippet, and just have the title as a link to the full question and anser

Here is a link to that particular website: http://prasadnutrition.com/faqs/

This also makes managing FAQs easy because they are all individual posts that you can manage in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using something like this:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/q-and-a/

Comment: I am trying it right now. Its... not working correctly. I put `[qa]` on my page and it showed the ToC of the FAQ but the links dont work. Nothing happens when i click on them. If i disable JS it will link me to the faq permalink but by default clicking with JS enabled does nothing. Maybe it would be easier if i wrote my own html generating util. Its probably only 200lines to do anyways. I may delete that plugin. I dont want to spend time fixing it for newest chrome/firefox/wordpress